How can I store the answers of a Gravity Forms multi page form in an array?
I have a multi page Gravity Form that is 4 questions, and each are multiple choice radio buttons.
I am looking for a way to store each answer in an array so I can execute some functionality with that array after the form is submitted.
Current JavaScript:
    // Global array to store answers
    var answers = [];

    // Function to capture answer for the current question and store it in the global array
    function captureAnswer() {
        // Find the currently visible page
        var currentPage = jQuery('.gform_page_visible');
        // Get the question number based on the page index
        var questionNumber = currentPage.index() + 1; // Index is zero-based, so add 1
        // Get the selected radio button value
        var selectedValue = currentPage.find('.gfield--type-radio input:checked').val();
        // Store the selected value in the global answers array
        answers[questionNumber - 1] = selectedValue; // Subtract 1 to match array index
    }

    // Function to handle form submission
    function handleFormSubmit(event) {
        // Prevent the default form submission
        event.preventDefault();
        // Capture answer for the current question
        captureAnswer();
        // Check if all questions have been answered
        var allQuestionsAnswered = answers.every(function(answer) {
            return answer !== undefined;
        });
        // If all questions have been answered, log the answers
        if (allQuestionsAnswered) {
            console.log(answers);
        } else {
            console.log("Please answer all questions before submitting.");
        }
        // Allow the form submission to continue
        this.submit();
    }
    (function($){
        // Attach event handler to form submission
        $('#gform_3').submit(handleFormSubmit);

        // Attach event handler to radio button change
        $('.gfield--type-radio input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
            // Capture answer for the current question when a radio button is changed
            captureAnswer();
        });
    });


Here is an example, I think it is enough to move forward.
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        function handleFormSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            var answers = [];
    
            // We always have checked inputs here (even after the step changes, inputs remain checked)
            var checkedInputs = $(this).find('.gfield--type-radio input:checked');
    
            //After the previous/next/submission we update our answers
            checkedInputs.each(function (index) {
                var input = $(this);
                answers.push({
                    'name': input.attr('name'),
                    'value': input.val()
                });
            });
    
            // Allow the form submission to continue
            this.submit();
        }
    
        // Be sure to replace with your form ID
        $('#gform_1').on('submit', handleFormSubmit);
    })

You can also take a look at the documentation on gravity forms.
If you are familiar with PHP this may be useful:  https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_submission/
